# How to install and make the character up of objects, using Android box2d?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I don't know how to install the extension of andengine box2d, so I have been watching tutorials of how to but my version of android studio is 1.3.1 so I can't understand.

I am developing a simple game like mario bross, so i have to make the principal character can be on some sprites (objects), if someone has a better solution.

Comment: If you look for in google, there are lots of tutorials updated to 2015 and lastest versions of android studio. Theres a good old tutorial i have always used and works fine: http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.in/2014/05/settings-up-andengine-in-android-studio.html

Comment: The first thing is to update Android Studio to version 2.2.